# google analytics traffic increase drastically when using setTimeout() function for GTM, GA, GTAG & FB scripts

Tags: google-analytics, settimeout, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, facebook-pixel

I am using this code to load the tracking scripts 3000 ms after page load to optimize page speed.

I have checked using the chrome extension `tag assistance legacy by google` plugin and no major issues are recorded other than `Same web property ID is tracked twice` on google analytics

```
<body onload="loadtracking()">
<script>
    function loadtracking(){
        loadgtm();
        loadfbpixel();
        loadga();
        loadgtag();
    }
</script>
<script>
    function loadgtm() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxx');
            // window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        }, 3000);
        return true;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function loadfbpixel(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.defer=true;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', 'xxxxx');
            fbq('init', 'xxxxx');
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
            fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration', {
                content_name: 'Sign up',
                content_category: 'xxxxxx'
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
<script>
    function loadga(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        
            ga('create', 'xxxxx', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            ga('send', 'event', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
<script>
    function loadgtag(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            scriptgtag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptgtag.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxx";
            scriptgtag.async = true;
            document.body.append(scriptgtag)

            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
        
            gtag('config', 'xxxxx');
            gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'xxxx'});
        }, 3000);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

But the traffic on GA increased drastically once I implemented this code by x 15

[increase in traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pizr7.png)

I cant seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: There might be 2 place to find out. 1. Is your GTM has installed the GA code again? 2. Is there any average number we can compare from before and after.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading Google Analytics to the page more than once (potentially even more if you're also loading it through Google Tag Manager) and it's firing a pageview for each of those loads. Let's step through each of your `<script>` blocks.

```html
<script>
    function loadgtm() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxx');
            // window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        }, 3000);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

This starts by loading GTM to the page. In order that its own triggers properly work, it's typically advised that this run in the `<head>` tags of your page. It loads asynchronously and non-blocking so running it on your page would hardly impact perceived page speed.

If you have a GA tag installed within GTM, this accounts for at least one pageview.

```html
<script>
    function loadfbpixel(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.defer=true;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', 'xxxxx');
            fbq('init', 'xxxxx');
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
            fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration', {
                content_name: 'Sign up',
                content_category: 'xxxxxx'
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

This simply loads the Facebook pixel, so we'll skip over it, except to say that I would instead advise loading this within GTM triggered at pageview.

```html
<script>
    function loadga(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        
            ga('create', 'xxxxx', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            ga('send', 'event', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

That brings us to the first of your explicit Google Analytics installs. Assuming you're not running something like this from within GTM, this sends a pageview and your event after your 3000ms timeout. Again, from an interest of minimizing page speed impact, you should use the built-in Google Analytics tag within GTM and augment it with the event you wish you fire (though I advise making the switch to GA4 before the [collection cut-off](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en) next year).

```html
<script>
    function loadgtag(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            scriptgtag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptgtag.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxx";
            scriptgtag.async = true;
            document.body.append(scriptgtag)

            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
        
            gtag('config', 'xxxxx');
            gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'xxxx'});
        }, 3000);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

This brings us to the Gtag loader, which is really just a means of loading a small GTM instance to your page that bundles the Google Analytics tag. This would account for your second pageview in GA. Since you have GTM installed to the page, you shouldn't be using this loader at all and should instead opt for the built-in GA tag within GTM.

Best case, you're double-counting pageviews. Worst case, you're counting 2x + however many GA pageview tags you're firing off within GTM.

My advice:

- Install the Google Tag Manager function without the timeout as high within the `<head>` tags as you can as provided by their installation instructions.
- Install your Facebook tag as an HTML script (drop your timeout function) and trigger to execute at Page View.
- Install the built-in "Google Analytics: Universal Analytics" tag, configure accordingly and trigger to run at Page View.
- Install the built-in "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration" tag, configure accordingly and trigger to run at Page View. This will be used by other GA4 tags for the base configuration, but also fires a pageview event without need for a second event-specific tag for the same.